# Connect legend of two graphs in plotly dashboard

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard, interactive

I have made a required graph(bar and pie) in python dash using plotly express library. But now I want my pie chart should change according to bar chart legend (say when select 2-3 days or any) and vice Versa when select topic as (duplicate) from below sample data and code

```
    server= Flask(name)
    
    app = dash.Dash(name, server=server)
    
    data = {

    'CPU': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    'Overall_TAT': ['0-2 days', '2-4 days', '>6 days', '0-2 days', '2-4 days', '>6 days'],
    'Topic': ['Duplicate', 'Calculation', 'Documents', 'Fresh', 'Duplicate', 'Calculation'],
    'Tag': ['part', 'toss', 'part', 'part', 'toss', 'part']
}



TAT_new_non_toss = pd.DataFrame(data)
app.layout=html.Div([
        
    html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
    id='tat_dropdown',
    options=[
        {'label':'Overall_TAT','value':'Overall_TAT'},
        {'label':'Credit_to_Toss','value':'Credit_to_Toss'},
        {'label':'Toss_to_Today','value':'Toss_to_Today'},
    ],
    value='Overall_TAT',
    ),
    html.H2(id='card-title', children="Card Type"),
    dcc.Graph(id='percentage_bar_chart')
    ],style={'width':'50%','display':'inline-block'}),

    html.Div([
    html.H2(id='card-title_pie', children="Reject Distribution for ALL CPU"),
        dcc.Graph(id='pie_chart')    
    ],
        style={'width':'50%','display':'inline-block'}),
        
])

@app.callback(
    Output('percentage_bar_chart','figure'),
    [Input('tat_dropdown','value')]
)

def graph(selected_tat):
    try:
        
        df_tat=TAT_new_non_toss.groupby(['CPU',selected_tat]).size().reset_index(name='count')
        df_tat['percentage']=df_tat.groupby('CPU')['count'].transform(lambda x: (x/x.sum())*100)

        fig=px.bar(
        df_tat,
        x='percentage',
        y='CPU',
        color=selected_tat,
        barmode='stack',
        orientation='h',
        color_discrete_sequence=['#104E8B','#1874CD','#1C86EE','#474747'],
         )
        fig.update_layout(title=f'TAT Distribution: {selected_tat}',
                        legend=dict(
                x=0.5, 
                y=-0.2, 
                orientation='h',
                yanchor='bottom',
                xanchor='center'
            ))

        return fig
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return{}

@app.callback(
    Output('card-title', 'children'),
    [Input('tat_dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_card_title(selected_tat):
    return f"TAT Distribution where Toss is raised - {selected_tat}"

@app.callback(
    Output('pie_chart','figure'),
    [Input('percentage_bar_chart','clickData')]
)

def pie_chart(clickData):
    try:
        TAT_new_non_toss_topic=TAT_new_non_toss[TAT_new_non_toss['topic'].notnull()]
        if clickData is not None:
            selected_cpu=clickData['points'][0]['y']
            filtered_data=TAT_new_non_toss_topic[TAT_new_non_toss_topic['CPU']==selected_cpu]
            topic_counts=filtered_data['topic'].value_counts()
            fig=px.pie(values=topic_counts.values,
                      names=topic_counts.index,

            color_discrete_sequence=['#2085ec','#72b4eb','#0a417a','#8464a0','#cea9bc','#323232'],
            )
        else:
            fig=px.pie(TAT_new_non_toss_topic,
                      names='topic',
                      color_discrete_sequence=['#2085ec','#72b4eb','#0a417a','#8464a0','#cea9bc','#323232'],)

        
        return fig
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return{}
    
@app.callback(
    Output('card-title_pie', 'children'),
    [Input('percentage_bar_chart', 'clickData')]
)

def update_card_title_pie(clickData):
    if clickData is None:
        return "Reject Distribution for ALL CPU"
    else:
        selected_cpu = clickData['points'][0]['y']
        return f"Reject Distribution for - {selected_cpu}"
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance